# Find the closest rectangle to a given rectangle in any of four directions

Tags: algorithm, geometry, game-development, computational-geometry, user-experience

Given a few dozen rectangles that are non-overlapping but clustered arbitrarily close together, how can the rectangle above, below, to the left, or right of any particular rectangle be chosen?

1. Given a rectangle R, how can the **closest** rectangle(s) above, below, left, and right be found? (geometric algorithm)
2. In some search direction from a particular rectangle R, if two other rectangles S and T are equally close to R, then which of S and T should be selected?

The context: in a game, a particular rectangle R is considered active. When the user presses an arrow key or uses a 4-direction controller to move in some direction--up, down, left, or right--then just one rectangle up, down, left, or right should be selected.

So what's desired is an efficient algorithm to choose the closest rectangle(s) in some direction relative to a selected rectangle R, and also some logic for choosing just one rectangle if there are multiple rectangles.

---

I have already tried many different methods, including: calculating the distance between vertices, centroids, calculating angles, etc., and while these methods worked well, in specific arrangements of rectangles they gave completely bad and unintuitive results.

Here's an example set of rectangles. Blue is the active rectangle. The goal is to pick just one rectangle in each of the up, down, and right directions.

[image]

Comment: Given that the information about the rectangles is in a list whose order is not controlled by the algorithm, what can you do but search the entire list to check each rectangle in it? Aside from that, what do you mean by “visually closest”? Is that something other than (using “up” for example) the non-active rectangle that shares some vertical line with the active rectangle and whose bottom border is the least distance above the active rectangle’s top border? (In other words, the first rectangle you can get to by going up from some point in the active rectangle.)

Comment: Is the question actually to define “visually closest”? The one that is least confusing to the user to select when they press one of the four arrow keys?

Comment: Erm, if your rectangles are all aligned with the axes in a Euclidean plane, the problem should be fairly simple. Do you want a _general_ algorithm, though, one thar’s suitable for n ≥ 2 dimensions containing rectangular bodies of any orientation?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: the problem is not that I have to iterate through all the elements of the list (because that is obvious), but what calculations should be made to choose a reasonable rectangle for activation. When writing about the "visually closest" to a given direction, I mean one that will be intuitive for humans.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt: this is a 2D space, and the only thing known is the number of rectangles and their position and dimensions. As I stated in the post, the position and dimensions of the rectangles can be any, without overlap. All edges of the rectangles are aligned to the X and Y axis, like in the example illustration.

Comment: You should rewrite the question. You are not looking for a search algorithm, so “Is there any known search algorithm for this?” is the wrong question to put in the post, and the title is misleading. You are looking for a criterion for selecting which rectangle a human would deem to be closest in a given direction, not an algorithm for finding it. And I am not sure that is a programming question.

Comment: Such questions belong on https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Interfaces like this are never intuitive. [Consider this subset of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KV8p.png). If either A or B is active, and the direction is down, then C is the only choice. But when C is active and the direction is up, do you go to A or B? The user will expect to go back to the previous rectangle, i.e. the intuitive choice is determined by the movement history. But then you need to decide how much history is useful to retain. Bottom line: if you want this to be intuitive for the average user, then there must be exactly one choice in each direction for each rectangle.

Comment: The meaning of "visually closest" isn't clear. You mention "unintuitive results," which suggests you have an idea intuitive results would be. Please indicate in four additional diagrams which rectangle you expect to be found for each of the four directions. Also, is this a homework problem? Or could you tell us what practical problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @user3386109: exactly. What I'm looking for is an algorithm that would allow me to travel around rectangles in this way, so that the user can use the arrow in the opposite direction to the one used to return to the previously active control. And the main problem is that the layout of the rectangles is never known (can be freely changed any time). I am asking what mathematical/geometric properties should be used so that I can not only select a reasonable rectangle, but also be able to undo the movement and return to the previous rectangle.

Comment: @Rethunk: this is not homework. I'm currently working on a GUI system for a game, and what I'm asking about is ultimately intended to be used to move focus between controls, using only the four cardinal directions. This algorithm should be universal, because it is not known how the interface will be built (what the layout of controls will be). In addition, the layout may change in runtime — controls may be added or removed, some may be dynamically enabled or disabled etc.

Comment: Re “also be able to undo the movement and return to the previous rectangle”: As [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109)’s example shows, there is no stateless algorithm for this. With C to the right of A and of B, expecting “left” to undo a “right” that arrived at C requires knowing which came first. (And that becomes more of a problem if the list changes, as you say it can.) And even if you remember the entire history, if the user goes right from A to C and then down to D, you might want left and up to get back to A, that gets tricky since there is no “right” to D…

Comment: … to undo, and choosing something left of D presents several problems. There might not be any good candidate. There might be a good candidate but it might have something above it and below A, so an “up” from it either has to go to that thing (and not complete the left-up undo of the right-down that got to D) or jump to A, which might be visually counterintuitive even though it is undoing the right-down. I do not think this is a Stack Overflow problem.

Comment: @furiousprogramming, okay. I have some ideas what would work efficiently here, but please label the rectangles A, B, C, etc. around your blue rectangle and indicate which should be found via left, right, up, and down. The two rectangles to the right of the blue one are an interesting case: the upper right rectangle shares more vertical extent, but the lower right rectangle is bigger. In that case the user could go right, then down to reach the lower right rectangle, correct?

Comment: 1. represent rectangles as 2D BBOX `(x0<=x1,y0<=y1)`  2. for each direction check coresponding coordinate for example x+ (right) check distance between `x1` of selected rectangle A and `x0` of searched rectangle B and select those that have minimal `A.x1-B.x0` while `A.x1>=B.x0` (create list of them) 3. now just select the one that have biggest overlap in y axis with selected rectangle `A`. ... for each direction you just swap 0,1 indexes or x,y coordinates the rest is the same...

Comment: I will start a new topic and try to describe the problem better, as well as add more diagrams to better illustrate the problem. Thank you for your answers so far.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as @Spektre, and had some rough diagrams in the works. A few questions to consider: Are coordinates represented as integers or floats? Is there a maximum ratio between the largest rectangle dimension and smallest? (How small can a rectangle be relative to the largest?) Are the rectangles represented on screen (or could they be) for the gamer so that you could pre-attentively highlight which rectangles would be next? I also have some thoughts on UI intuitiveness.

Comment: @furiousprogramming, I've edited the question in the hope it will be opened again. If the question is not re-opened, then I suggest asking two separate but related questions: first a question about the rectangle search that yields ALL rectangles of equal closeness to some selected rectangle (computational geometry); and then a second question asking which rectangle should be chosen, if multiple are found in some search direction (UX / game design).